# How to write equation of continuity and equation of motion in arbitary co-ordinates?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rJAS.png)

In the above problem: I am unable to figure out how the equation of continuity and equation of motion could directly be written in terms of the variable ***s***.

***s*** is not the usual cartesian co-ordinate but the distance along the curved tube which itself is not symmetric.

So how did the two equations arise? And when is this possible?

Thanks